# Getting all files in UWP app folder

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

For UWP, it is easy to get all files in the app local folder as:

`IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();`

You can now iterate on the **files** list and even get further info on individual files.

I would like a similar all-file-getter for an app folder, for instance, consider the **/Assets** folder where app ***.png** files are stored.
Single file with a known name is no problem; I can refer to it quite easily as:

`StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"))`

My question is, therefore, is there a similar thing for getting all files in an app folder, such as **/Assets** folder? Logically, it should be something like `StorageFile.GetFilesFromApplicationFolderUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets"))` but unaware if an equivalent of the LocalFolder shown above exists.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can access you installation folder by using [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx). Therefore your code can look like this:

```
StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFolder assets = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var files = await assets.GetFilesAsync();
```

Comment: Phew! that was pretty quick and thank you. Funny enough I used Package.InstalledLocation a while ago and focusing on the ms-apps:/// scheme made me forget. Thanks again - you saved my time.

Comment: @user5525674 No problem, I was just passing by ;)

Comment: For me, GetFolderAsync("SomeFolder") will throw an exception if it is empty.

Comment: @jchristof If the folder doesn't exist then it will throw exception - this is normal.

Answer (score 3):

```
var storageFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var files = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata