# Saving an image asset to a storage file in a local folder in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, storage

I have an image in the Assets folder of my UWP project (`"Assets/Nophoto.jpg"`) that I would like to save as a `StorageFile` in the app's local folder.

The only way I have seen to save an image in a `StorageFile` is with the `FilePicker`.

```
FileOpenPicker FilePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            FilePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            FilePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            FilePicker.CommitButtonText = "Picture";
            FilePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

            PictureFile = await FilePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

How would I go about storing an image file(.jpeg, .png, .bmp, ect..) in a `StorageFile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question:

> I have an image in the Assets folder of my UWP project ("Assets/Nophoto.jpg") that I would like to save as a StorageFile in the app's local folder.

You can do it for example like this - getting file via *Uri* (note that it can also [be accessed via *InstaledLocation* folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33742791/2681948)):

```
StorageFile sourceFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Nophoto.jpg"));
await sourceFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
```

Once you have a *StorageFile* (no matter if obtained via picker/from installation folder/other) then you can copy it to other *StorageFolder*. If you have an image via a stream or pixel buffer, then you can create a file and write to it by using a stream.