# How to get all text files from a folder "C:\Test" in UWP using c#?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I'm learning to build for windows 10 using UWP and c#. I'm trying to get the text file count and name of all the files in a folder which is at "C:\Test". Please help.

Comment: You can start from here and read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the UWP file access permission issue, you cannot access files directly from disk. If you want to access specific file, you can use FolderPicker or broadfilesystemaccess.

About [FolderPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#pick-a-folder-complete-code-listing), you need to access folders by interacting with a picker.

About [broadfilesystemaccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions), you need to add broadFileSystemAccess capability in the manifest and access is configurable in **Settings > Privacy > File system** to allow your app to access file system.

In addition, about how to get all text files, you can use [QueryOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.queryoptions) class to query the specified file type.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = "using FolderPicker or broadFileSystemAccess to get it."
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
        StorageFileQueryResult queryResult = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
        var files = await queryResult.GetFilesAsync();
        int count = files.Count;
        foreach (var file in files) {
            string name = file.Name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can access any file location using path in UWP application But by using [Package.InstalledLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx) you can access to your installation folder. Therefore to get files form Test" folder inside Installation directory your code can look like this":

```
StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFolder assets = await appInstalledFolder.GetFolderAsync("Test");
var files = await assets.GetFilesAsync();
```

But in C# application

```
Directory.GetFiles(string.path);
```

Method on System.IO Namespace but to count specific type of file we use following overload of same method:

```
Directory.GetFiles(string path, string search_pattern , SearchOption);
```

You can specify the search option in this overload.

- **TopDirectoryOnly**: Includes only the current directory in a search.
- **AllDirectories**: Includes the current directory and all the subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse
  points like mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

For text Files you can specify search pattern as:

```
// searches the current directory and sub directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
// searches the current directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
```

Comment: This won't work for UWP apps, since they don't have access to `C:\Temp` and `System.IO` doesn't know how to deal with capabilities / permissions.

Answer (score 1):

UWP application can run in different windows platform like window 10, windows mobile, so the path you are trying to access might not be available in all those platform. Although you can access the installation folder path. See this link: [Getting all files in UWP app folder](http://UWP%20application%20can%20run%20in%20different%20windows%20platform%20like%20window%2010,%20windows%20mobile,%20so%20the%20path%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20access%20might%20not%20be%20available%20in%20all%20those%20platform.%20Although%20you%20can%20access%20the%20installation%20folder%20path.%20See%20this%20link:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742696/getting-all-files-in-uwp-app-folder)

What are you trying to achive by access the location 'C:\Test'? If you are trying to download files and store it to that location, you can instead save those files in the installation directory folder and later access those files from there.